# How to check if B:B contains specific text and then sum C:C in Excel Online?

Tags: excel

I searched for this issue, but all of them show `if cell A1 contains X, then true value is Y and false value is Z`.

But this is my sample in Excel Online:

```
Person  debt (usd)  credit (usd)
personA 5.00        0.00    
personB 0.00        10.00   
personA 10.00       0.00    
personB 5.00        0.00    
personA 0.00        10.00
```

I want this: `if cell B:B contains personA ==> (add all debts) - (add all credits)`.

And: `if cell B:B contains personB ==> (add all debts) - (add all credits)`.

I'm using Online Excel.

Comment: Did you try `SUMIFS` yet?

Comment: `=SUMIFS(C:C,B:B,'personA')-SUMIFS(D:D,B:B,'personA')`

Comment: @ScottCraner thanks, but when I use, Excel says `The formula in this cell contains an error`.

Comment: @BigBen no, but I'm reading docs how to use it.

Comment: Sorry, playing in sql and the quotes are different: `=SUMIFS(C:C,B:B,"personA")-SUMIFS(D:D,B:B,"personA")`

Comment: @ScottCraner thanks, it worked. I was trying `sumif` myself with single quotes too and I did not know Excel does not behave them equally in this situation.